# Checksum Based Storage Jfrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, checksum

I have Jfrog Artifactory SAAS version installed in my org. In this I (admin though) donot have access to the server. I have been lately thinking on is it possible to have checksum based storage for artifactory on client side? If yes then what could be the best utility which is more suitable for this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want Artifactory on your own server, you can get the on-prem version instead of the SaaS version. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Why do you need access to the server? how is this related to a checksum based storage? what does it mean having a checksum storage on the client side?

Comment: since m a client for installed artifactory I want my artefacts have a checksum generated.. so if I have a saas version of artifactory how m I going to verify the checksum generated on both sides?